ABCD-DCBA=1638. Find all possible values of A, B, C, and D such that they all are positive integers.
I have a question in my math homework, since I am preparing for a math competition. This question would also benefit people who are preparing for math competitions, and I really want to know how to deal with simllar questions in the future.
Let's say there are 2 integers, ABCD and DCBA. Imagine we put it into a cryptarithm where you have
ABCD
-DCBA
=1638.
Find all solutions to A, B, C, and D.
I wrote ABCD and DCBA as 1000A+100B+10C+D, and DCBA as 1000D+100C+10B+A, respectively.
Then, I get:
(1000A+100B+10C+D)-(1000D+100C+10B+A)=1638.
999A+90B-90C-999D=1638.
I don't know how to proceed with this after, can you please help with this?

We can represent the letters as algebraic expressions: $$1000A + 100B + 10C + D - 1000D - 100C - 10B - A = 1638$$ This simplifies to $$999A + 90B - 90C - 999D = 1638$$ Dividing by 9 results in $$111(A-D) + 10(B-C) = 182$$ Since both $A-D$ and $B-C$ are integers ranging from $-9$ to $9$, the only values that would work are if $A-D = 2$ and $B-C = -4$. Thus we get two equations: $$A = D + 2$$ $$C = B + 4$$ Any four integers on $[0,9]$ that satisfy these two expressions will result in a valid answer for $ABCD$ and $DCBA$. Depending on whether or not digits can repeat, you can figure out how many possible ways to arrange these letters from here.
